# SQL Server - Get column who have specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which returns :

```
id    |  value
 1         a
 1         a
 1         b
 2         a
 2         a
```

I want to get only id who have only the value `a`. So the id 2

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and having clause to check if all the rows have value 'a' for a given id:

Using `Count`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(*) = count(case when value = 'a' then 1 end);
```

Or using `Sum`

```
select id
from t
group by id
having SUM(case when value = 'a' then 0 else 1 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next code:-

```
Select id  
from #test
group by id 
having sum (case when value = 'a' then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

The clue is passing `0` for `'a'` and pass `1` for other, then having sum equals `0`

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly slower than @Gurwinder Singh's answer but can be more readable if performance is not your top priority.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (id int, [value] char(1))

INSERT INTO tmp values (1,'a'),(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'a')

SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM tmp a
WHERE [value] = 'a'
    AND id NOT IN (
        SELECT id FROM tmp
        WHERE [value] <> 'a')
```